# Excel 2019 ActiveX combobox as dropbox does not show all items after a selection is made

Tags: excel, vba, activex

When the combobox has no entry and the list button is clicked, the entire range is displayed. When the combobox already has a value, the list displayed is only from the value's position to the end. In my experiment, if the last item in the list is in the combobox, displaying the list just lists that item. I need the entire list to be displayed so the user can change the selection.

The combobox has a ListFullRange of SignUp!A3:B182 and a Style of frmStyleDropDownList. The ListFillRange has only 4 entries in it for my experiment. In production the ListFillRange has an entry for every participant; sometimes as many as 120 entries in the list (180 capacity).

Anybody out there with a clue as to how I should redefine the combobox? I would also take suggestions for code (VBA) to make the combobox behave the wanted way.